# Why can't I encrypt with OpenSSL?

Tags: encryption, openssl, rsa

I'm having trouble creating a public/private key pair and using it to encrypt a file.

First I generate the private key:

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048
```

Then I extract the public key:

```
openssl rsa -in private.pem -out public.pem -outform PEM -pubout
```

so that I can encrypt my file:

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey public.pem -in myfile.txt -out file.ssl
```

but then I'm told:

```
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
unable to load Private Key
7064:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:696:
    Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

I don't understand... why is it trying to load a *private* key? How do I encrypt a file using the public key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to specify that it's a public key, it needs to be done [explicitly](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkeyutl.html). This works (I'm using `pkeyutl`, the specific "utl"s are deprecated):

```
openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -in myfile.txt -pubin -inkey public.pem -out file.ssl
```

You have to be careful where you put the `-pubin` - if it is specified after the `-inkey public.pem` for example, you will again receive the same error as before. Yeah, I know.